# knitr presentation print slides

Tags: r, printing, knitr, presentation

I have a knitr presentation saved as html. I would like to print it keeping the slides intact. Currently if I try to print, the structure of the slides get broken. I will appreciate if anyone have any suggestion.

Thanks.

Comment: Works for me if I "print" in landscape format.

Comment: I've had the same problem many times. Getting the knitr presentation from HTML or markup to a pdf or to print it is a nightmare... If that problem was solved I would use knitr for every presentation I ever make.

Comment: By "knitr presentation" do you mean ioslides - i.e. `RStudio➡File➡New File➡R markdown...➡Presentation➡ioslides`? If so, you have to use Chrome to do the printing (choose landscape like @RomanLuštrik said and it "just works").

Comment: I knit a presentation to html, and print to a pdf in landscape.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answer. It did not work for me. when I try to print the slides there is no option to change to landscape. But if I want to print anything else landscape option comes back. I think it has something to do with knitr presentation. I don't know what I did wrong. I am using chrome on MAC(maveric OS X 10.9.4). My slides are created as described by @hrbrmstr above.

Comment: Actually I generated the presentation from RStudio menu `File->New File->R Presentation` and my file extensions are .Rpres. If I open new presentation using the method suggested by @hrbrmstr the landscape option appears but the printing layout of the first title slide is still broken. I tested with knitr minimum example that opens by default.